# How do I exclude all values in a row where the first instance of this value occurs? (R Dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset, df

```
Subject

Hi
hello
RE: Hello
RE: How is work
No
Ok
RE: What time are 
Hello RE: are you
```

I would like to exclude all rows where the first word is RE:

Subject

```
Hi
hello
No
Ok
Hello RE: are you
```

Here is the dput:

```
 structure(list(Subject = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
 7L), .Label = c("hello", "HI", "No", "ok", "RE: Hello", "RE:   How     is work", 
 "RE: What time are"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",       row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```

I have tried this:

```
   df %>% 
   filter(Subject!= %RE:)
```

I do not know how to formulate the code so that it will exclude only if is the first instance within the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use :

```
subset(df, !grepl('^RE', Subject))
```

Or with `grep` and `invert = TRUE`

```
df[grep('^RE', df$Subject, invert = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
```

---

Same can be implemented in `dplyr` as well

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!grepl('^RE', Subject))
```

and with `slice` and `grep`

```
df %>% slice(grep('^RE', Subject, invert = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Subject, pattern = "^[RE]", negate = T))
```